# write to string array char by char

Tags: c++, arrays, string

i'm working on a project and i came to a deadlock. i'm having trouble figuring out how to write a string char by char in an array?

i mean:

```
string my_str[10];
```

i want to access my_str[0]'s first char.

i tried this:

```
    string tokens[10];
    (&tokens[0])[0] = 'a';
    (&tokens[0])[1] = 's';
    (&tokens[0])[2] = 'd';
```

it works like tokens[0]='a', tokens[1]='s' etc.

then i tried:

```
string tokens[10];
(&tokens[0])[0][0] = 'a';
(&tokens[0])[0][1] = 's';
(&tokens[0])[0][2] = 'd';
```

when i compile it errors (string substring out of range) but when i click abort it works. what is wrong with this code?

Comment: Take a look at what the '&' symbol means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a character at a time to a string, you can use either `push_back` or the `+=` operator. E.g.:

```
tokens[0] += 'a';
tokens[0] += 's';
tokens[0].push_back('d');
```

Answer (score 0):

The string you created using

```
string tokens[10];
```

are empty. That is, you have 10 empty `string`s. If you want to access a character in there you'll need to resize them, e.g.:

```
string tokens[10];
for (string& str: tokens) {
     str.resize(3);
}
tokens[0][0] = 'a';
tokens[0][1] = 's';
tokens[0][2] = 'd';
```

When you use, e.g.,

```
(&tokens[0])[2] = 'd';
```

you first get a pointer to the first `string` in the array, dereference that index `2`, and assign a `string` which is converted from the character `'d'`, i.e., `string('d')` to it. That is, this statement is equivalent to

```
token[2] = 'd';
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use string::at for this. Like so:

```
char x;
string s[10];
s[0] = "asdf";
x = s[0].at(0);
printf("%c", x);
```

prints a.

Comment: Using  `std::string::at()` (or `std::vector<T>::at()`) is a Bad Idea: the problem is that it almost certainly hides a programming error and throws an exception instead. In any case you access `at()` the implementation needs to check if the element is out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the public member function in the String class name : c_str().
It returns in fact Returns a pointer to an array that contains a null-terminated sequence of characters (i.e., a C-string) representing the current value of the string object: to be specific, it's a char array that contains the exact equivalent of the string object value.
Let's say we have a :

```
string array_of_strings[10];
```

To access the first char of array_of_strings[0] and print it is simply to write:

```
std::cout << array_of_strings[0].c_str()[0] << endl;
```